# iframe into nextjs

Tags: reactjs, iframe, next.js, fetch, embed

I want to put some HTML file into my code, something like this

```js
<FlexContent gap="16" justify="space-between">
  <iframe src="../../public/assets/maps/cityMap.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</FlexContent>
```

This file is an interactive map, it has the HTML, the Scripts and the SVG together, I Want to show it but it doesn't work
thank you

- I've imported the element
- Tried with `getStaticProps`

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
  // your fetch function here
  const data = await fetch("../../public/assets/maps/cityMap.html");

  return {
    props: {},
  };
};
```

I have this Error:

```
Failed to parse URL from "../../public/assets/maps/cityMap.html"
```

Comment: I think the issue here is you are using the path relative to the code you're writing, instead of the path relative to the public URL - see the answer by @tpj

Answer (score 1):

It's already in a public folder then you can do this.

```
<iframe src="./assets/maps/cityMap.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

use react-iframe library to display html in iframe

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).